# How to use map_location='cpu' due to "RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False"

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conda

I was trying to download the following model at https://pytorch.org/hub/nvidia_deeplearningexamples_tacotron2/

```
import torch
tacotron2 = torch.hub.load('nvidia/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2')
```

I received:

```
>>> import torch
>>> tacotron2 = torch.hub.load('nvidia/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2')
Using cache found in .cache\torch\hub\nvidia_DeepLearningExamples_torchhub
...
  File "Anaconda3\envs\env3_pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 79, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU.
```

So I used the following with `map_location='cpu'`, but still get the same error.

```
>>> tacotron2 = torch.hub.load('nvidia/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2', map_location='cpu')
```

torch.version.cuda shows a version but torch.cuda.is_available() is false.

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.version.cuda
'9.0'
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

- How to get around this error related to `map_location` as I used exactly the command error message asked to use?
- How can I use cuda in loading the model?

Answer (score 6):

[`torch.hub.load`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html#torch.hub.load) does not specifically support `map_location`, it only forwards the extra arguments to the loading of the model, so it's implementation dependent whether that would be support.

In this case it is not supported, the loading is implemented in [NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub - hubconf.py](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/9189f070934705a4be1856a69f5dada3c4c9c2d9/hubconf.py#L115) and it does not pass any `map_location` to [`torch.load` when the checkpoint is loaded](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/9189f070934705a4be1856a69f5dada3c4c9c2d9/hubconf.py#L143).

That means you need to load the checkpoint manually and apply it to the model. Thankfully, the model can be loaded with the same configuration without loading the checkpoint, by setting `pretrained=False` and the checkpoint can be loaded separately with [`torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/hub.html#torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url), which supports `map_location`. There is only a small change that is required to the state dict, because it was trained with `DistributedDataParallel`, which wraps the module, such that every `layer` in the model became `module.layer`. In the state dict that `module.` prefix needs to be stripped.

```py
tacotron2 = torch.hub.load('nvidia/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2', pretrained=False)

checkpoint = torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url('https://api.ngc.nvidia.com/v2/models/nvidia/tacotron2pyt_fp32/versions/1/files/nvidia_tacotron2pyt_fp32_20190306.pth', map_location="cpu")

# Unwrap the DistributedDataParallel module
# module.layer -> layer
state_dict = {key.replace("module.", ""): value for key, value in checkpoint["state_dict"].items()}

# Apply the state dict to the model
tacotron2.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

Comment: @michale Jungo 
So I understand the issue with hub.load was that the hubconf.py in the nvidia-github link wasn't implemented as it's usually expected, correct? 

I tried ```>>> tacotron2 = torch.hub.load('nvidia/DeepLearningExamples:torchhub', 'nvidia_tacotron2', pretrained=False)```. But I keep getting `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '.cache\\torch\\hub\\torchhub.zip` even though there is no other process. Why is that?

Comment: I was able to get past the WinError above using instruction at this link https://medium.com/@ron.warshawsky.2009/fixing-pytorch-1-1-github-model-load-permission-error-on-windows-c293ff9672ae, but now I see another issue during loading the checkpoint: ```IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=[], unexpected_keys=[])```. when doing `load_state_dict`. Any resolution?  
```
>>> tacotron2.load_state_dict(state_dict)
IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=[], unexpected_keys=[])
>>>```

Comment: Is there a way to see summary of the model layer-by-layer and see it in graph-form? When I try `>>> summary(tacotron2)` I get `TypeError: summary() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input_size'`

Comment: I'm guessing that`summary()` refers to [pytorch-summary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary). If so, you need to give the input size that you would feed to the model, because it needs to run a forward pass with some dummy data to figure out what layers are actually used. Other than that, if you print the model directly, you get an overview of the modules. Most of the time those are in order, but anything that doesn't go sequentially through it (e.g. multiple branches) won't be reflected by that.

Comment: I was referring to pytorch-summary, but couldn't figure out what the `input_size` would be for tacotron-2, or how to specify the input to the model.

Comment: For the checkpoint loading issue, any way to fix the error?
```>>> tacotron2.load_state_dict(state_dict) IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys=[], unexpected_keys=[]) >>>```